# Error 503 on Cloud Run for a simple messaging application

Tags: python-3.x, rest, flask, post, google-cloud-run

I have built a simple Python/Flask app for sending automatic messages in Slack and Telegram after receiving a post request in the form of:

```
response = requests.post(url='https://my-cool-endpoint.a.run.app/my-app/api/v1.0/',
    json={'message': msg_body, 'urgency': urgency, 'app_name': app_name},
    auth=(username, password))
```

, or even a similar curl request. It works well in localhost, as well as a containerized application. However, after deploying it to Cloud Run, the requests keep resulting in the following 503 Error:

```
POST 503 663 B 10.1 s python-requests/2.24.0 The request failed because either the HTTP response was malformed or connection to the instance had an error.
```

Does it have anything to do with a Flask timeout or something like that? I really don't understand what is happening, because the response doesn't take (and shouldn't) take more than a few seconds (usually less than 5s).

Thank you all.

--EDIT:
functions.py follow:

```
import slack
import os, sys
from dotenv import load_dotenv
import datetime
import pymysql
import requests

load_dotenv()

def get_tel_slack(app_name):
    try:
        mysql_password = os.getenv('mysqlpass')
        my_sql_user = os.getenv('user')
        host = os.getenv('host')

        con = pymysql.connect(host = host, user = my_sql_user, passwd = mysql_password, db = 'starman', cursorclass=pymysql.cursors.DictCursor)
        cursor = con.cursor()

        cursor.execute(f"SELECT a.ID as App_ID, a.App_Name, g.Users_ID, g.Pref_Channel, u.Telegram, u.Slack_ID FROM `App` AS a LEFT JOIN `Group` AS g ON g.App_ID = a.ID LEFT JOIN `Users` AS u ON u.ID = g.Users_ID WHERE a.App_Name = '{app_name}';")

        rows = cursor.fetchall()
        users = []
        telegrams = []
        pref_channel = []
        for row in rows:
            users.append(row['Slack_ID'])
            telegrams.append(row['Telegram'])
            pref_channel.append(row['Pref_Channel'])
        con.commit()
        con.close()
    except:
        print(f'{app_name} not found on Starman database.')
        sys.exit(f'{app_name} not found on Starman database.')
    return users, telegrams, pref_channel

def send_message(message, urgency, app_name):
    users, telegrams, pref_channel = get_tel_slack(app_name)
    date = datetime.datetime.now()
    if (str.lower(urgency) in ['urgent', 'urgente']):
        message = f'Olá, foi detectada uma falha na aplicação {app_name}, às {date.time().hour-3}h{date.time().minute}min{date.time().second}s, de {date.date().day}/{date.date().month}/{date.date().year}. \n{message} \nA falha foi considerada grave, e deve ser corrigida o mais rápido possível.'
        send_telegram(message, telegrams)
        send_slack(message, users)
    elif (datetime.datetime.now().time().hour-3 >= 18) or (datetime.datetime.now().time().hour-3 <= 8):
        message = f'Olá, foi detectada uma falha na aplicação {app_name}, às {date.time().hour-3}h{date.time().minute}min{date.time().second}s, de {date.date().day}/{date.date().month}/{date.date().year}. \n{message} \nA falha é pontual e pode ser resolvida em breve.'
        send_telegram(message, telegrams)
        send_slack(message, users)
    else:
        telegrams2 = []
        users2 = []
        message = f'Olá, foi detectada uma falha na aplicação {app_name}, às {date.time().hour-3}h{date.time().minute}min{date.time().second}s, de {date.date().day}/{date.date().month}/{date.date().year}. \n{message} \nA falha é pontual e pode ser resolvida em breve.'
        for channel in pref_channel:
            if channel == 'Telegram':
                telegrams2.append(telegrams.index(channel))
            else:
                users2.append(users.index(channel))
        send_slack(message, users2)
        send_telegram(message, telegrams2)
    return 'Message sent!'

def send_slack(message, users):
    client = slack.WebClient(token=os.getenv('SLACK_TOKEN'))
    for user in users:
        client.chat_postMessage(channel=user, text=message)
    return 'Message sent via Slack!'

def send_telegram(message, telegrams):
    auth_token = os.getenv('TELEGRAM_TOKEN')
    for telegram in telegrams:
        send_text = f"https://api.telegram.org/bot{auth_token}/sendMessage?chat_id={telegram}&parse_mode=Markdown&text={message}"
        response = requests.get(send_text)
        print(response.json())
    return 'Message sent via Telegram!'
```

app.py follow:

```
from flask import Flask, jsonify, make_response, request
from flask_httpauth import HTTPBasicAuth
from dotenv import load_dotenv
from werkzeug.security import generate_password_hash, check_password_hash
import os
import datetime
import functions

load_dotenv()

auth = HTTPBasicAuth()

app = Flask(__name__)

users = {
    os.getenv('username'): generate_password_hash(os.getenv('password'))
}

@auth.verify_password
def verify_password(username, password):
    if username in users and check_password_hash(users.get(username), password):
        return username

@app.route('/functions/api/v1.0/', methods=['POST'])
@auth.login_required
def send_message():
    message = request.get_json()['message']
    urgency = request.get_json()['urgency']
    app_name = request.get_json()['app_name']
    return functions.send_message(message, urgency, app_name)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True, host='0.0.0.0')
```

Also my Dockerfile:

```
FROM ubuntu:20.04
ENV TZ=America/Sao_Paulo
RUN ln -snf /usr/share/zoneinfo/$TZ /etc/localtime && echo $TZ > /etc/timezone
ENV LANG C.UTF-8
RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get install -y python3 python3-pip
RUN pip3 install Flask==1.1.2 python-dotenv==0.15.0 flask_httpauth==4.2.0 pymysql==1.0.2 slackclient==2.9.3 requests==2.24.0
ADD src /app/src
WORKDIR /app/src
CMD ["python3", "app.py"]

Thanks!
```

Comment: Are you using WebSockets? Also are you sure you’re not encrypting the response? Cloud Run documentation has a getting started tutorial with Flask, I recommend checking that out. There's a chance basic authentication is messing with something here. Is your app public or private?

Comment: Can you share your code to have a reproductible case in our side?

Comment: There are two main Snippets and my Dockerfile. I will post them right there.